# a matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Consider the following matrix whose entries everywhere except the superdiagonal are $0$ and whose entries on the superdiagonal are 1's:
>   $$\left( \begin{array}{cccc...cc}
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0\\
> ...\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 1\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 & 0
>  \end{array} \right)$$
>   a) Prove $A^n =0$, but $A^ {n-1} \neq 0 $.
>   b) Find all matrices which commute with $A$ and show that they must be of the form $c_0+ c_1A+c_2A^2+\cdots+c_{n-1}A^{n-1}$.

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $x^n$, so $A^n =0$. But how to prove $A^{n-1 }\neq 0$? How to solve b)?

Comment: It can be seen that this is in fact the Frobenius companion matrix of the monomial $x^n$...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $e_i$ denotes the vector with a $1$ at position $i$ and zero elsewhere. What is $Ae_i$? What is $A^{n-1}e_n$?

Answer (score 1):

$A^2$ will have the second super-diagonal non zero and everything else zero.
By induction, the $i$th superdiagonal will be the only place containing ones
in $A^i = A^{i - 1} A$. Thus $A^{n - 1}$ will have a one on its $\left( 1, n
\right)$th entry and zeros everywhere else and $A^n = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a tedious way of doing $b)$ (checking entries).

Here's a more theoretic proof. Since $A^{n-1}\neq 0$, there is some $e$ such that $A^{n-1}e\neq 0$. It's easy to prove that $(e,Ae,\ldots, A^{n-1}e)$ is linearly independent, hence a basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $C(A)$ denote the set of matrices that commute with $A$. $C(A)$ is a linear subspace of $M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Let $f:C(A)\to \mathbb R^n, B\to Be$.

$f$ is linear, and injective since $Be=0\implies \forall k, A^kBe=B(A^ke)=0$. $B$ is then $0$ on a basis of $\mathbb R^n$, hence $B=0$.

The injectivity of $f$ implies $\dim C(A)\leq n$.

Here we already have $I_n,A,\ldots, A^{n-1}\in C(A)$, and these matrices are linearly independent (because the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $X^n$). Hence $\dim(C(A))=n$ and a basis of $C(A)$ is $I_n,A,\ldots, A^{n-1}$.